# Adding element to a array works, but doesnt show up in other switch statement

Tags: c#, arrays

In my code, I try to create 2 arrays and be able to add more elements to those arrays and then print them out. I print whole arrays in switch case 3 and nothing happens, but when I copy that code to case 1 it works perfectly. That means it takes the old array instead of the "updated" one. Can someone help me?

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    
    

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        bool fortsatt = true;

        while (fortsatt)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Lägg till blogginlägg (1)");
        Console.WriteLine("Skriv ut inlägg (Skriv titeln) (2)");
        Console.WriteLine("Skriv ur alla blogginlägg (3)");
        Console.WriteLine("Avsluta (4)");

            string[] posts = { "jag åt inte frukost", "jag åt gott middag", "jag åt hamburgare" };
            string[] titles = { "Frukost", "Middag", "Mat" };

            string menu = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (menu)
            {
                case "1":

                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Mata in en text");
                    string inmatat = Console.ReadLine();       

                    List<string> list = new List<string>(posts.ToList());
                    list.Add(inmatat);
                    posts = list.ToArray();

                    Console.WriteLine("Mata in en titeln");
                    string titel_imatning = Console.ReadLine();

                    List<string> list_of_titles = new List<string>(titles.ToList());
                    list.Add(titel_imatning);
                    titles = list_of_titles.ToArray();

                    break;
                    
                case "2":

                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv titeln:  ");
                    string search = Console.ReadLine();
                    bool found = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (titles[i] == search)
                        {
                            
                            Console.WriteLine("\tDet är vad jag har hittat: " +
                                "\n\tTiteln: " + titles[i] +
                                "\n\tInlägg: " +
                                posts[i] + "\n\t");
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!found)
                        Console.WriteLine("\t Kunde inte hitta ");
                    break;

                case "3":

                    foreach (var value in posts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(value);
                    }
                    
                    break;

                case "4":
                    Console.WriteLine("Tack för att du använde min kod");
                    fortsatt = false;
                    break;


                default:                        
                    

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You are each time creating the arrays from scratch in each of your main while loop run.

Put the Arrays outside the

```
while(true)
```

Like this:

```
      bool fortsatt = true;

            string[] posts = { "jag åt inte frukost", "jag åt gott middag", "jag åt hamburgare" };
            string[] titles = { "Frukost", "Middag", "Mat" };

        while (fortsatt)
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Lägg till blogginlägg (1)");
         Console.WriteLine("Skriv ut inlägg (Skriv titeln) (2)");
         Console.WriteLine("Skriv ur alla blogginlägg (3)");
         Console.WriteLine("Avsluta (4)");

            string menu = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (menu)
            {
                case "1":

                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Mata in en text");
                    string inmatat = Console.ReadLine();       

                    List<string> list = new List<string>(posts.ToList());
                    list.Add(inmatat);
                    posts = list.ToArray();

                    Console.WriteLine("Mata in en titeln");
                    string titel_imatning = Console.ReadLine();

                    List<string> list_of_titles = new List<string>(titles.ToList());
                    list.Add(titel_imatning);
                    titles = list_of_titles.ToArray();

                    break;
                    
                case "2":

                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv titeln:  ");
                    string search = Console.ReadLine();
                    bool found = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (titles[i] == search)
                        {
                            
                            Console.WriteLine("\tDet är vad jag har hittat: " +
                                "\n\tTiteln: " + titles[i] +
                                "\n\tInlägg: " +
                                posts[i] + "\n\t");
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!found)
                        Console.WriteLine("\t Kunde inte hitta ");
                    break;

                case "3":

                    foreach (var value in posts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(value);
                    }
                    
                    break;

                case "4":
                    Console.WriteLine("Tack för att du använde min kod");
                    fortsatt = false;
                    break;


                default:                        
                    

                break;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Even after I put them outside of the while loop, my code still can't print additional elements :/

Comment: I have tried your code in LinqPad it prints out additional elements in switch case 3. You are only printing out `posts` and not `titles` in case 3.

Comment: hmmm... I'm using visual studio. Switch case 3 should only print posts, so it works correctly. Thank you.

Comment: No. It doesnt work on my computer. https://imgur.com/a/3inKKmN  you have a screenshot here.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your solution? I copied the answer I provided to visual studio it works.

Comment: I even created new file and copied your code and it doesn't work. The build I use is Console Application so it should be alright. Well, if the code works, I will send it to my teacher and cross my fingers that it will work for him Hahahahaha Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score -1):

You seem to show the menu in a loop. And you initialize the arrays `posts` and `titles` within that loop. So all changes made by the user in the first run, will be discarded by the array re-initalization in the next run / loop.

Solution: initialize the array outside the loop.

```
    bool fortsatt = true;
    string[] posts = { "jag åt inte frukost", "jag åt gott middag", "jag åt hamburgare" };
    string[] titles = { "Frukost", "Middag", "Mat" };

    while (fortsatt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lägg till blogginlägg (1)");
        Console.WriteLine("Skriv ut inlägg (Skriv titeln) (2)");
        Console.WriteLine("Skriv ur alla blogginlägg (3)");
        Console.WriteLine("Avsluta (4)");
        //....
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It was dumb of me to put them there. Yet the changes I make still doesn't show up :/